# wget to print errors, but nothing otherwise

Tags: wget

How can I have wget print errors, but nothing otherwise?

In the default behavior, it shows a progress bar and lots of stuff.

In the --no-verbose version still prints one line per downloaded file, this I don't want.

The --quiet option causes it to be totally quiet, even in the case of an error, it doesn't print anything.

Is there a mode in which it prints errors, but nothing else?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are very good answers in this question, be sure to check them out, but what I've done is this:

```
wget [wget options] 2>&1 | grep -i "failed\|error"
```

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me with 16.04 ubuntu bash.

Answer (score 20):

Use curl, no point guessing what every error will look like.

```
[wizard@laptop ~] curl -s -S http://www.google.coccm/ > /dev/null && echo "TRUE"
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'www.google.coccm'
[wizard@laptop ~]$ curl -s -S http://www.google.com/ > /dev/null && echo "TRUE"
TRUE
```

> -s/--silent
>
> ```
> Silent mode. Don’t show progress meter or error messages. Makes Curl mute.
> ```
>
> -S/--show-error
>
> ```
> When used with -s it makes curl show error message if it fails.
> ```

And if you need stderr on stdout for some reason.

```
curl -s -S http://www.google.coccm/  2>&1 1> /dev/null
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't handle typical HTTP errors (eg. 404 errors are suppressed this way), whereas the hacky wget method does.

Comment: Downvote: Although your suggestion is plausible, it does not answer the question.

Comment: Add -f/--fail to display an error message if the server returns an error code (e.g. 404)

Comment: This could be a great answer if, the question was about curl, or if curl had feature parity with wget. Unfortunately neither is the case..

Comment: nice advise and worth to know, still not an answer

Answer (score 5):

I don't see an option for that.  Do you need to know what the error is, or just if it happened?  If you happen to just need to know if there was error, you can use the exit status.

```
if ! wget -o /dev/null www.google.com/flasfsdfsdf; then
    echo 'Oops!'
fi
```

Or, maybe:

```
if ! wget -o logfile www.google.com/flasfsdfsdf; then
    cat logfile
fi
```

And you can change the cat to a grep command if you want to get fancy...

Comment: More simple way: wget -o logfile <url> || cat logfile

Comment: The more simple way is worse since you probably want to exit or do something different on error, in addition to displaying the error message.

Answer (score 3):

```
OUT=`wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/a http://example.com/ 2>&1` || echo $OUT
```

works. But it always truncates the output file, which you may or may not want.

Curl is better:

```
curl --fail --silent --show-error -o /tmp/a http://example.com
```

In case of an error it does not modify the output file.

Answer (score 2):

Redirect standard output to `/dev/null`, but keep the error output in your choice of shell.

In bash this would be:

```
wget [wget options] > /dev/null
```

**Edit:** So `wget` misbehaves. If all errors contain the word "error" in them you could pipe to `grep`

```
wget [wget options] 2>&1 | grep -i "error"
```

Comment: wget seems to send everything to stderr.

Comment: I added another option using `grep` to only output errors

Comment: `stderr` doesn't go through the pipe without help.

Comment: In the end I used wget [wget options] 2>&1 | grep -i "failed\|error"

Answer (score 1):

Since `wget` outputs all messages on `stderr`, you have to use redirection before you can pipe it to grep:

```
wget [options] 2>&1 | grep "^wget:"
```

This assumes that `wget` begins its error lines with "wget:".